How quickly could a probe reach the heliopause?
What if the goal of the Voyager program was instead to reach the edge of the heliosphere (effectively, interstellar space) within a decade? What would be the amount of fuel required and is this amount realistic?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You might need to still clarify "assuming cost is not a concern (within reason)."  What's reasonable?  Apollo-program-level funding?  GDP of USA?  GDP of the world?  (I am not one of the downvoters)

@ErinAnne I understand, I worded it very poorly and for some reason it's hard for me to make it come out right.

I'm going to write an answer assuming a couple of things:

the work required to improve markedly on the performance of Saturn V, including new/expanded pads for larger-than-Saturn successors like Nova, would lead to unacceptable launch delays on-the-order-of two decades, so a Saturn V-centric solution is desirable

the launch date is selected such that the vehicle can proceed directly toward the near-side of the heliosphere (which isn't entirely spherical) in the direction the Earth is traveling, making the goal "traverse roughly 100 AU / 15 billion km in less than a decade, i.e. achieve a radial-out heliocentric velocity greater than roughly 47.5 km/s", and the launch vehicle only has to contribute roughly 17.7 km/s of that


Using as references

Tsiolkovsky rocket equation
Saturn V
Voyager 2 (which launched first)
Apollo SM specifications

we find a standard-ish Saturn V stack (S-IC, S-II, S-IVB, and Apollo SM without the CM) falls right around the exact value (spreadsheet)



Stage
delta-V (km/s)
Gross mass (kg)
Dry mass (kg)
Fuel mass (kg)
Payload mass (kg)
Starting mass (kg)
Ending mass (kg)
Exhaust velocity (km/s)




S-IC
3.35
2,214,000.00
137,000.00
2,077,000.00
644,441.90
2,858,441.90
781,441.90
2.58


S-II
5.08
496,200.00
40,100.00
456,100.00
148,241.90
644,441.90
188,341.90
4.13


S-IVB
5.36
123,000.00
15,200.00
107,800.00
25,241.90
148,241.90
40,441.90
4.13


Apollo SM
3.92
24,520.00
6,110.00
18,410.00
721.90
25,241.90
6,831.90
3.00


Voyager 2





721.90




Total
17.71




3,677,089.50





This admittedly makes some strange assumptions--the Apollo SM would have to be given some additional capability from the CM to perform its burn, and given the profile we want to fly (just keep on burning instead of needing propulsion after days of coast) it'd be much better to stack an additional hydrolox stage instead of a hypergol.  But I think these numbers demonstrate that leaving the heliosphere in a decade is possible using Voyager-era technology with some minimal additional development put into it.

This assumes a direct throw.  A Jupiter gravity assist can contribute at least 13 km/s without delaying things appreciably; a Saturn assist might also be a net positive.

@Mark an earlier version of the question (and the title I guess) were asking if gravity assists would make it faster. I didn't want to go so far as that, but an answer that actually attempting to optimize the earliest-to-100AU (or earliest to a better approximation of the heliosphere boundary) would absolutely be better than mine.

According to Horizons, Voyager 2 picked up ~10 km/s in the Jupiter flyby. https://i.sstatic.net/QXAOaUnZ.png I have other related graphs at https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/58971/16685

Thank you so much! This answered my question exactly. I thought it would take a lot more than just a single Saturn V, but looking back I'm not sure why I thought this. It would only have to go a few times faster and the Saturn dwarfs the Titan 3E. Again, thanks.

I think a Venus gravity assist would also be interesting to calculate out. it obviously doesn't get you nearly as much as Jupiter, but you can get there a lot faster and more consistently, so it might be surprisingly competitive

y'all feel free to post more answers with optimizations!  I don't need to hear any more proposed gravity assists.
